# RelativeLayout.BELOW fails to function

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Basically, I've been trying to place a bunch of EditText and TextViews programmatically, all within a RelativeLayout (I have to do it programmatically because the amount of stuff is variable depending on how many "employees" the user has entered). Now, I only need ten pieces of data per "employee", so I decided to keep track of the data using id's in base 10 (ie Employee 1 gets id 0-9, Employee 2 gets id 10-19, etc.). However, every time I use LayoutParams.addRule(int,int) function and manually input my own id, it fails to pick it up. If I use the addRule(int,int) function using "R," it works. The only reason I can come up with that would explain addRule's failure to respond to the manually inputed id values is if my math (for the id-values) is wrong, but if you look at my code, the math is pretty self-explanatory. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong because this is maddening.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for(int i=0;i<u.getTemp().size();i++){
        int index=10*i;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if(i==0)
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.start_date);
        else
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,index-1);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        TextView empName=new TextView(rl.getContext());
        empName.setTextSize(26);
        empName.setText(u.getTemp().get(i).getName());
        empName.setId(index++);
        empName.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        rl.addView(empName);

        TextView empNum=new TextView(rl.getContext());
        empNum.setText("Employee Number: " + u.getTemp().get(i).getNum());
        empNum.setId(index++);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams empNumLayout=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        empNumLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,empNum.getId()-1);
        empNumLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        empNum.setLayoutParams(empNumLayout);
        rl.addView(empNum);

        EditText regHours=new EditText(rl.getContext());
        regHours.setHint("Regular Hours");
        regHours.setId(index++);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams regHoursLayout=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        regHoursLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,regHours.getId()-1);
        regHoursLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        regHours.setLayoutParams(regHoursLayout);
        rl.addView(regHours);
    }
```

*Notes: rl is the relativeLayout I placed in the xml file.

Comment: Instead of creating it this way, I think you can use a list view...

Comment: Agreed with @sravan in that there are better ways to approach this problem.  Can you give us an example of your XML layout?  I believe you can solve the problem in a much cleaner way.

Comment: `You'd better use an XML layout,` instead of messing with Java, `to build an UI`.

Comment: @DerGol...lum
The problem is that I can't use an XML layout because the amount of EditTexts and TextViews changes with what the user has inputed.

Comment: @sravan I'll try the listView as soon as I get the chance, but I'm still not really sure what's wrong with my code. All the EditTexts and TextViews are appearing on the same upper-left corner of the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Maybe you can prepare a better layout, where the unneeded Views are GONE, and make them VISIBLE only when needed. But the ListView approach is better.

Comment: While LinearLayouts and ListViews are great, I would like to maintain the ability to put children next to each other not just underneath each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that ids have to be positive. The first TextView had an id of 0 which explains why the addRule didn't respond.

Answer (score 0):

I recently lost the reputation to comment :) so I am posting it as an answer. You can try using Linear Layout instead of Relative Layout. If you require any further assistance let me know. I'll help you out. :)

Comment: LinearLayouts are great, but I would like to maintain the ability to make children be next to each other not just below each other.